# Finding Increase/Decrease Intervals

Tags: calculus

Let's take the function $f(x) = {x^2 \over x-1}$, with $f'(x) = {x(x-2) \over (x-1)^2}$ as its derivative. Since $x = 1$ is not in the domain of $f(x)$ and $f'(1)$ does not exist, do we use $x = 1$ as a critical number when we divide the line into intervals? Or do we just use $x = 0, 2$?

Similarly, for $g(x) = {(2-x)(x+1) \over (x-1)^2}$ with  $g'(x) = {x-5 \over (x-1)^3}$. Do we use $x = 5$ or $x = 5$ and $x = 1$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use the critical points where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are undefined when you divide each line into intervals because they might reveal vertical asymptotes. When drawing the graph of your functions, you can draw the vertical asymptotes as dashed lines to remind you not to graph there. Indeed, the line of your graph can never cross a vertical symptote on pain of death!

In the case of $f(x)$, the slope is negative on both sides of the vertical asymptote. That means your graph tends to $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from the left and tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from the right.

In the case of $g(x)$, the situation is slightly different, the slope is positive on the left and negative on the right of the vertical asymptote. That means your graphs tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from both sides.

Comment: If we use x = 1 for f(x), wouldn't x = 0 and x = 2 be maximums and x = 1 be a minimum? The textbook solution has x = 0 as a max and x = 2 as a min.

Comment: If you are looking for local (relative) extrema, then you are right. If you are looking for global (absolute) extrema, then you might not be right. For example, try values around $1$ like $0.9999$ or $1.0001$, then you will notice these have lower and higher values respetively than your local extrema :)

Comment: Here's what I did for f(x)' http://prntscr.com/9at987.  A change from + to - is a max, and the opposite is true for minimums. According to the screeshot, my max point is x = 1, and x = 0 and 2 are minimums, but the textbook has x = 0 as the max and x = 2 as the minimum. I'm not sure which intervals to use.

Comment: If you are applying the first derivative test, notice that it assumes the function is continuous at all points in the open interval $(a,b)$ containing the critical number $c$. At the point $1$, the function is not continuous because it's undefined. If you try the values I suggested before, you will notice the function tends to $-\infty$ as you approach $1$ from the left and tends to $+\infty$ as you approach $1$ from the right.

Comment: For g(x)', here's what my prof did http://prntscr.com/9atcr8. He used x = 1 even though g(x) is not continuous on x = 1. I'm not sure whether to follow the textbook's example or his.

Comment: I understand that x = 1 cannot be a max or a min, but you're saying that we're allowed to use x = 1 to determine whether an interval is decreasing or increasing? If did use x = 1, my solution would be incorrect according to the text since my solution would make both x = 0 and x = 2 minimums VS. the textbook's max as x = 0 and min as x = 2. I'm really confused! Please save me

Comment: It might relieve some confusion to know you made a mistake in one of your printscreens: $f'(-0.5)$ is positive and $f'(0.5)$ is negative whereas you seem to have the opposite. You will then notice that you have negative slopes on both sides of $1$ for $f(x)$.

Comment: Oh! I forgot the power of 2 for (x-1). This makes complete sense now. Thanks a lot!